# Banner not fully covering top

Tags: css

I'd like to have my banner fill up the top of the website completely, how do I do that? There are some gaps as shown in the photo. Here is my css:

```
  <body>
    <div id="headerbanner"></div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </body>

body{
  background-image: url("../IMAGES/mountain1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#headerbanner{
  height: 70px;
  background-color:black;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to pinpoint the exact issue as you haven't provided a great detail of detail, context or code, but I believe issue is that your background image doesn't cover the container.

Try the following CSS rule

`background-size: cover;`

Your new CSS would be:

```
#headerbanner {
  height: 70px;
  background-color:black;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This should stretch the background image to fill the container, whilst retaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have tried your method but the result is still the same. I am using a div for the banner, could that be the reason?

Comment: I don't think so. Am I correct in understanding that the '#headerbanner` also uses an image as a background? (the image of the mountains shown in your question)

Comment: Would you be able to create a JSFiddle of your site so I could get a clearer picture? :)

Comment: The #headerbanner is not using any image as background. Here's the JSFiddle ( not sure if it works, its my first time using it). https://jsfiddle.net/5pg54zwm/1/

Comment: @Learning2code move the background image to your banner instead of having it on the body

Comment: @Pete I'd like the background image to show on the entire webpage, shouldn't it stay on the body?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not make the banner a background, that doesnt make sense.
instead use a fixed position and manually set it to 0px top, 0px right.
Consult this :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

NEXT THING TO CONSIDER:
Once you or your client has accessed the website, programmatically set the position, width and height depending on viewport of the client's browser. This can be accomplished with javascript, using the window.onload function.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to fixed the position manually but it does not work too

Comment: added a comment, may fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the help Max, I have solved the issue. I added margin: 0;
  padding: 0; to my css for body, and it solved the problem